# MySQL How to join records from another table which date is latest

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, join

I have following select SQL query:

```
SELECT i.instagrammer_id, CONCAT(i.first_name,' ',i.last_name) AS instagrammer_name, FLOOR(DATEDIFF (NOW(), i.date_of_birth)/365) AS age, i.date_of_birth, i.gender, i.email, i.created_date, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name_en) AS industrie_branch, coalesce(c.long_name, '')  AS long_name, s.social_id
FROM instagrammer AS i
LEFT JOIN social_login AS s ON s.instagrammer_id = i.instagrammer_id
LEFT JOIN industries_branches b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.industrie_branch_id, i.industrie_branch)
LEFT JOIN country_data c ON c.short_name = i.based_in_country
WHERE i.status IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY i.instagrammer_id
ORDER BY instagrammer_name DESC
```

and getting this records:

[image]

Now I want to join from one more table by matching from `social_id` which I am getting above SQL results but there is one condition, I need record which date is latest from `statistic_instagrammer_detail` table.

### Table: statistic_instagrammer_detail

```
id  instagrammer_id  followers  created_date
**  ***************  *********  *******************
28  440024439        190        2015-12-10 09:37:03
27  12095962         390        2015-12-10 09:36:03 
26  2238046564       544        2015-12-10 09:35:03
25  481959735        780        2015-12-10 09:34:04
24  440024439        151        2015-12-09 09:54:02
23  12095962         210        2015-12-09 09:53:02
22  2238046564       403        2015-12-09 09:52:02
21  481959735        659        2015-12-09 09:51:09
```

I want to add `followers` from above screenshot results:

```
followers
*********
190
390
544
780
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: In addition to remarks made below, to my way of thinking, there is no point including CONCAT and/or GROUP_CONCAT in PHP parsed queries - the latter especially so where the GROUP_CONCAT is the only aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a subquery on `statistic_instagrammer_detail` table that returns the `max(created_date)` from that table per `instagrammer_id` and then join `statistic_instagrammer_detail` table to it to get the `followers`.

```
SELECT i.instagrammer_id, CONCAT(i.first_name,' ',i.last_name) AS instagrammer_name, FLOOR(DATEDIFF (NOW(), i.date_of_birth)/365) AS age, i.date_of_birth, i.gender, i.email, i.created_date, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name_en) AS industrie_branch, coalesce(c.long_name, '')  AS long_name, s.social_id, st.followers
FROM instagrammer AS i
LEFT JOIN social_login AS s ON s.instagrammer_id = i.instagrammer_id
LEFT JOIN industries_branches b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.industrie_branch_id, i.industrie_branch)
LEFT JOIN country_data c ON c.short_name = i.based_in_country
LEFT JOIN (SELECT instagrammer_id,  max(created_date) as maxdate from statistic_instagrammer_detail group by instagrammer_id) t on i.instagrammer_id=t.instagrammer_id
LEFT JOIN statistic_instagrammer_detail st ON  i.instagrammer_id=st.instagrammer_id and t.maxdate=st.created_date
WHERE i.status IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY i.instagrammer_id
ORDER BY instagrammer_name DESC
```

Please note, however, that your query will run in mysql under certain configuration settings only and is against the sql standard, since it contains fields in the select list that are not in the group by clause, nor are aggregated.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT i.instagrammer_id, CONCAT(i.first_name,' ',i.last_name) AS instagrammer_name, FLOOR(DATEDIFF (NOW(), i.date_of_birth)/365) AS age, i.date_of_birth, i.gender, i.email, i.created_date, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name_en) AS industrie_branch, coalesce(c.long_name, '')  AS long_name, s.social_id,st.followers
FROM instagrammer AS i
LEFT JOIN statistic_instagrammer_detail as st ON  i.instagrammer_id=st.instagrammer_id
LEFT JOIN social_login AS s ON s.instagrammer_id = i.instagrammer_id
LEFT JOIN industries_branches b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.industrie_branch_id, i.industrie_branch)
LEFT JOIN country_data c ON c.short_name = i.based_in_country
WHERE i.status IS NOT NULL and st.created_date=(select MAX(created_date) from statistic_instagrammer_detail)
GROUP BY i.instagrammer_id
ORDER BY instagrammer_name DESC
```

Comment: Getting error `#1054 - Unknown column 'st.followers' in 'field list' `

Comment: still getting same error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'st.followers' in 'field list' `

Comment: @Mr.Happy you must be misding a table alias, which is in the above query. The problem with the above query is not what you experience (this error has probably been introduced by you), but the fact that it gets the overall max(created_date) from the statistics table.